# Add external libraries (dependencies) and reference them correctly in my python code

Tags: python, reference, external, libraries, libsodium

I try the following code to see if the library **sodium** can be located

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

# Taken from line 33 https://github.com/bgaifullin/pysodium/blob/master/pysodium/__init__.py

o = ctypes.util.find_library('sodium')

print o
```

This always returns "none"

Please how do I add external libraries (dependencies) and reference them correctly in my python code.

EDIT:

I am trying to work with pysodium it has a dependency on libsodium

I have downloaded libsodium, but i'm new to python...

I'm actually using PTVS 2.1 to get up to speed running python in my familiar dev environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. What you want is to import a library.
Put the pysodium directory under the script you want to use and then simply do

```
import pysodium
```

It is as simple as that.

Usually, what you do is install the libraries on your system, or in a virtualenv, and import them to your python script. Cloning the repository will not generally help unless the libraries you want to import are in the same directory as the script you're importing from.

I, personally, would recommend using **virtualenv** and **pip** together hand in hand. Read up on virtualenv, it will come very handy.

Assuming you have both virtualenv and pip, all you need to do is the following

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pysodium
```

This should create a virtualenv container, activate it and install pysodium inside. Your script will only work when the virtualenv is activated. You can deactivate it using the command **deactivate**.

Comment: I am trying to work with pysodium it has a dependency on libsodium

Comment: This is a bad way to do things but it should work if you try it.

Comment: i dont understand how you mean "bad way"?

Comment: It is generally a bad way to clone a library and put it inside your working directory to use it. The better way to go about doing it is as I suggested, using virtualenv and pip together.

Comment: oh, let me clarify, the library i'm trying to load is not a python  lib

Comment: Actually, it is. You need sodium installed on your system first and pysodium on top to interface with it. The library you are using is a python library that interfaces with a non-python library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67864/discussion-between-charleso-and-digisec).